# Uncaught TypeError: data is null

Tags: javascript, php, null

Me aparece este error en mi js y no encuentro solución por que antes me funcionaba. Algun consejo? intento graficar campos de mi base de datos en phpmyadmin

```js
 <script>
        function CargarDatosGraficoBar() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controlador_grafico.php',
                type: 'POST'
            }).done(function(resp) {
                var titulo = [];
                var cantidad = [];
                var a = [];
                var b = [];
                var c = [];
                
                var data = JSON.parse(resp);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    // Posiciónes de arreglo
                    titulo.push(data[i][0]);
                    cantidad.push(data[i][9]);
                    a.push(data[i][10]);
                    b.push(data[i][11]);
                    c.push(data[i][12]);
                }
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        labels: titulo,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Preguntas',
                            data: cantidad,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            y: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CargarDatosGraficoBar()">Grafico</button>
                        </div>
                        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Uncaught TypeError: data is null
CargarDatosGraficoBar https://crsseguridad.live/intranet/encustascrs/adminSatisfaccion/index.php:206     jQuery 6     CargarDatosGraficoBar https://crsseguridad.live/intranet/encustascrs/adminSatisfaccion/index.php:198     onclick https://crsseguridad.live/intran

Comment: Lo primero, que te devuelve controlador_grafico.php?

Comment: <?php
    require 'modelo.php';

    $MG = new Modelo_Grafico();
    $consulta = $MG -> TraerDatosGraficoBar();
    echo json_encode($consulta);
?>

Comment: Pero que valor te da?  porque te dice "data is null" debo entender que no trae datos... has una validación de "data" en tu JS.. en la linea de var data = JSON.parse(resp); estas diciendo que siempre trae datos, creo que ahi esta el error

Comment: Ya lo resolví, estaba llamando un procedimiento almacenado para imprimir unos campos de mi base de datos, cuando tenia que llamar con un SELECT * FROM.